# Longest Common Subsequence for k strings

Tags: algorithm

We all know that the LCS(Longest Common Subsequence) algorithm for 2 strings can be computed using Dynamic Programming for 2 strings with lengths m and n in O(mn) time and space.

Now if we consider k strings with lengths say n1,n2,....nk. How do we extend this algorithm to general case?

As I understand the DP solution we will have a space requirement of O(n1*n2...*nk) (k-dim array)

Is there an way to improve the space efficiency for the general case?

Comment: Good luck with the paywall, but [this article](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-56024-6_18) discusses it.